# How to log (or see) all inserts performed in a talend job

Tags: talend

I have a Job in talend that inserts data into a table.

Can I get this SQL sentences (ie "insert into tabla(a,b)values(....)")?

Comment: Do you want to see the results of a query in a job, or execute a certain query?

Comment: I wanted to see the sentence itself, to store it, or to know of sth went wrong.

Comment: You could look for it in the generated code, can't think of another way tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the data inserted by adding **tLogRow** but if you want to see the generated insert on real time you can use the debugger.

For example, for the following job:
[image]

Above you can see the data inserted from an excel file to a mysql table. This was generated using **tLogRow**. But if you want the sql generated sentence, by using the debug you can see it here:

[image]

Hope to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply place a tLogRow component either before or after your database output component to log things to the console if you are interested in seeing what data is being sent to the database.

Comment: You want to see the SQL statement being generated? Why?

Comment: I've had some errors when changed my Oracle source (to Oracle RAC). I wanted to know why the inserts are in the older database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to see (it could be nice as an improvement in new releases). My problem, was when I change de source of my database output (Oracle SID to Oracle RAC), the inserts were made in the older database.

I fix it change the xml code in the "item" file. With the change older params attached to Oracle SID were stil there.

Thanks a lot!! Have a nice weekend  Goon10 and ydaetskcoR!

Comment: Check the JAVA code generated. You'll see an: INSERT INTO <table> (columns) VALUES (?,?,?) thats the insert. Talend uses preparedStatements to do the inserts, thus only 1 insert will be generated and sent.

Comment: Rephrased my comment to an answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the generated JAVA code. You'll see an:

> INSERT INTO  (columns) VALUES (?,?,?)

thats the insert preparedStatement. Talend uses preparedStatements to do the inserts, thus only 1 insert will be generated and sent. In the main part of the component it will call

> setString(value,position)

Please refer to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html